# Execute a file remotely with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run a batch file remotely using Invoke-Command

```
PS C:\Users\ale> Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER -ScriptBlock { Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\Test\Extract.bat'" }
```

The batch file is supposed to output 3 files in C:\Test\ and is running fine locally.
When I execute the command above, here's the output I receive in powershell

```
NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : SERVER
 
1_03102021.csv
2_03102021.csv
3_03102021.csv
```

As I check there was no file in the remote directory. Any advice please?

Comment: You don’t need Invoke-Expression, just call the bat file itself.

Answer (score 0):

To call a bat file in powershell where the path has no spaces you can call it directly

```
PS C:\> c:\temp\bat.bat
```

If the path/name contains spaces, quote the path and use the command invoke operator `&`

```
PS C:\> & "c:\temp\bat with spaces.bat"
```

So for your command it would be just

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER -ScriptBlock { C:\Test\Extract.bat }
```

Comment: Thanks and noted. I tried your suggestion but the result was still the same. No output file was created

Comment: I could see that being the case if the bat is trying to write to a non local drive. If it is a network path even on the calling host it would be subject to the double hop rule. Good luck.